# Screenshot app that can take screenshots in any view

Tags: iphone, ios

I know it is possible to take screenshots inside your own app but I was wondering if it is possible to have an app that allows you to capture screenshots in any view as long as the app it open. Im pretty sure its not possible but I just wanted to double check. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to interact with other applications outside of your sandbox on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Its an iOS default. If you press the `Home + Power` button at the same time the iOS device will take a screenshot and store the screenshot in your photos app.

Comment: I don't think he's looking to have the user trigger this.

Comment: My idea was to possibly create an app that allows a user to be able to take a "screen video". I didn't think is was possible but thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you would like to spy on other apps. Like the user's banking information. Now that the question is rephrased, I'll bet you know the answer (and why it won't change even if you file a feature request).

Comment: No. The app would be used by the user to take "screen videos" that would be stored into their photo app. Not to spy on peoples banking information.

Comment: But you need to generalize the ability you're asking for. If iOS doesn't let you do something, it is very often because it can be too easily abused.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)saveScreenshot {        
    // Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    CGSize size =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    // Create the screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    // Put everything in the current view into the screenshot
    [[self.view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    // Save the current image context info into a UIImage
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Save the screenshot to the device's photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self,
                                   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

    if (error) {
        // Handle if the image could not be saved to the photo album
    }
    else {
        // The save was successful and all is well
    }
}
```